# In CiviCRM Event Paypal payment not reflecting multiple participants

Tags: paypal

In CiviCRM - We have an event with multiple participants. Registration of participants works well and reflects total price (https://www.thesel.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/info&Itemid=269&reset=1&id=278). However when you go to pay in PAYPAL - total cost shown is only for ONE participant and not multiple as reflected in registration.

Have had no issue doing this in past years. Also tried same procedure in past years event and am now encountering the same error.

We are using version 5.20.0.

Comment: What CiviCRM version are you using now? Do you know what version it was on when it was working? Sounds like a bug.

Comment: We are currently using the new 5.20 civiCRM, so it is very possible. I was hoping that it was something easier to resolve.

Comment: @Alan Dixon, Thank you. Yes we are using CiviCRM 5.20 - I have submitted an issue request on Bug Reporting.
This is a critical issue for our event - any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Has this been resolved or is there a work-around? We are having the same problem with version 4.47. We want/need to enable multiple registrations since a lot of the info is the same and just process the total fee as a single payment using Paypal.